# PHP Session not saving in session file

Tags: php, session, session-variables

quick question

I'm new to PHP but I can't get the session variables to save across pages.

Sample setting code step2.php

```
<?php session_start();
include("header.html");
$_SESSION['num'] = $_POST['num'];
?>
```

Sample retrieving code step3.php

```
<?php session_start();
...

...
echo "<br>session num " .  $_SESSION['num'] . " " . session_id();
echo "<br />";
Print_r ($_SESSION);
```

I have checked the permissions of the session folder and it seems fine, I've chucked it up to 777 at the moment. A session file is stored for my session but it is empty. I echo the $_SESSION['num'] further down in step2.php and it reads fine, but it is as if the $_SESSION means nothing and is treated as a local variable I guess.

step3.php outputs :

```
session num 64881284326c8492bc6ebe73747db934
Array ( )
```

I must be missing something completely stupid. Do you need to finalize and write the sessions or something?

Comment: Have you examined the variables in your post request?  Have you tried adding a static value to the session - ex. $_SESSION['num'] = 'test value';?

Comment: did you check permission of session folder ???

Comment: and might be $_POST[num] may be empty please check this as well as

Comment: You really need to examine `$_POST[]` to see if it contains what you think it does, and try setting a session variable to something static like `test` as recommended above. That alone alienates the most likely causes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, yeah using a static help me - i think the session was taking an array from the post. Fixed by

```
$_SESSION['num'] = intval($_POST['num']);
```